# Why do I get the error: Cannot run 'uic': "execvp: No such file or directory" for a PySide2 program under macOS Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina, pyside2

I want to execute a program which was written in python using PyQt5 and then migrated to PySide2 under MacOS Catalina.
With PyQt5 it was executing fine.
I have installed PySide2 like PyQt5:

```
python3 -m pip install PyQt5
python3 -m pip install PySide2
```

macOS was restarted afterwards.

Now, with PySide2 installed, I am getting an error in macOS when I am trying to load an Ui-file.

MRE which works under Linux, Windows and macOS Catalina:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Standard library imports
import sys

# Third party imports
from PySide2.QtCore import (QMetaObject,
                            Slot)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
                               QWidget,                               
                               QPushButton,
                               QHBoxLayout,
                               QMessageBox)

def show_about():
    msg = QMessageBox()

    msg.setText("About this app.")
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)

    msg.exec_()
    
class MainWindow(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):        
        aboutButton = QPushButton("About")
        aboutButton.setObjectName("aboutButton")
        
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(aboutButton)        
        
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
                
        self.setWindowTitle('Buttons')        
            
    @Slot()
    def on_aboutButton_clicked(self):
        show_about()
        
def main():    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

MRE which fails under macOS Catalina, but works in Linux and Windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Standard library imports
import sys

# Third party imports
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
                               QMainWindow)

from PySide2.QtUiTools import loadUiType
   
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, loadUiType("win_main.ui")[0]):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Python 3.8.5 (/usr/local/bin/python3)
>>> %Run pyside2_win_main.py
Cannot run 'uic':  "execvp: No such file or directory"  -  Exit status  QProcess::NormalExit  ( 255 )
 Check if 'uic' is in PATH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dee/ownCloud3/rma2/pyside2_win_main.py", line 12, in <module>
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow, loadUiType("win_main.ui")[0]):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

File structure for simplicity of test case:

```
/Users/dee/ownCloud3/rma2/pyside2_win_main.py
/Users/dee/ownCloud3/rma2/win_main.ui
```

PySide2 version 15.5.0, shiboken2==5.15.0.

macOS Calatina v10.15.06

Python 3.8.5 64bit (downloaded from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-385/), no HomeBrew etc.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: mmm, File "/Users/dee/ **ownCloud3** /rma2/src.pyside2/win_main.py" and /Users/dee/rma2/ui/win_main.ui

Comment: @eyllanesc: Done. Updated my original post with a working and failing MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative paths as they are susceptible to errors as it will depend on how the script is run, instead build an absolute path:

```
import os.path


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
ui_file_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "win_main.ui")


Ui_Class, _ = loadUiType(ui_file_path)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Class):
    # ...
```

Also add at the top of your file, since it seems that when python was installed, the option to add the necessary paths to the environment variables was not marked:

```
import PySide2 
import os.path  

uic_dir = os.path.dirname(PySide2.__file__) 
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + uic_dir
```

Comment: Reworked it as in your suggestions.

Ui_Class, _ = loadUiType(ui_file)
   
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Class):
...

Now it fails here:
line 17 ->

Python 3.8.5 (/usr/local/bin/python3)
>>> %Run pyside2_win_main.py
Cannot run 'uic':  "execvp: No such file or directory"  -  Exit status  QProcess::NormalExit  ( 255 )
 Check if 'uic' is in PATH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dee/ownCloud3/rma2/pyside2_win_main.py", line 17, in <module>
Ui_Class, _ = loadUiType(ui_file_path)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @ProfP30 1) **don't use global variables**, 2) what does *Now it fails here: line 17 * mean? you must point me the full error message

Comment: See full reworked code here:

https://pastebin.com/pZtyY5Uc


line 17, in <module> Ui_Class, _ = loadUiType(ui_file_path) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: See error here (screenshot): https://pasteboard.co/Jq1SpU4.jpg

Comment: @ProfP30 add this code `import PySide2
import os.path

uic_dir = os.path.dirname(PySide2.__file__)
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + uic_dir` on top your fille

Comment: Thank you!
This did the job!
Can you explain a bit? You're expanding the PATH environment variable; but why is this even necessary? And why only on macOS Catalina? Not necessary on Linux and Windows.

Comment: @ProfP30  1) The PATH contains the default paths where the OS looks for binaries (executables and libraries). 2) I have seen similar problems in windows when python is installed without checking the option to add its path to the environment variables, in linux that case can also happen but generally it is installed in the default places (/usr, /usr/bin , etc) and

Comment: @ProfP30 3) the same applies for MacOS but it seems that the problem is your custom installation, when you used the python installer did you check the option that indicated that the python path was added to the environment variables? The problem is not the OS.